# Ionic Controller and Service: "TypeError:... is not a function"

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic's mobile app and stuck by the error

> TypeError: t.getCases(...).then is not a function

The following are my controller and service concerned:

## Service

```
starter.services.factory('appData', function() {

  return {
      getCases: function() {

        var cases =[ 
          {case_id: 1, description: 'headache'},
          {case_id: 2, description: 'fever'},
          {case_id: 3, description: 'stomachache'}
        ];

        return cases;
    }
  } 

})
```

## Controller

```
starter.controllers.controller('mainViewCtrl', function($scope, appData) {

  appData.getCases().then(function(data){
      $scope.cases = data.cases;
   });  

  console.log("mainViewCtrl completed");
})
```

Please note that I run the gulp script to merge and "uglify" all JS files before building the package file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I know next to nothing about Angular, but from the error message alone, it seems really likely that whatever you're providing `getCases` to is expecting it to return a *promise*, not a simple object.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, yes you are right, as long as the Factory returns a Promise everything works like a charm! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) said, in order to use "then" (asynchronous call), you have to return a promise from the service, able to fetch in your controller afterwards:

```
starter.services.factory('appData', function($q) {

  return {
      getCases: function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        var cases =[ 
          {case_id: 1, description: 'headache'},
          {case_id: 2, description: 'fever'},
          {case_id: 3, description: 'stomachache'}
        ];

        //attach data to deferred object
        deferred.resolve(cases);

       //return promise to be catched with "then"
       return deferred.promise;

    }
  } 

})
```

If you might want to return an error as callback, you might just reject the promise by calling deferred.reject(error) (while error is an optional error message/object).

Here is another good link which helped me to get the concept of asynchronous programming with promises in angular:
[$q.defer](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but if the Factory just returns deferred.resolve, there would be another error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" at the Controller side. The problem is solved until the Factory returns deferred.promise instead.

Comment: Of course, you have to return the promise of the deferred object. Somehow a bit of code got lost....  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have service and I am try to call from different controller but I am fetching issue first time it works fine. Another time tried to call give me 
" TypeError: object is not a function "

Really appreciate if you give me kind of solution.